# How to properly use InAppBrowser in Cordova 5.x.x?

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, inappbrowser

I'm migrating from an older version of Cordova, and I have an issue, I'm trying to open link in the native browser when a specific button is pressed, my code is the following:

The button is in a string:

```
"<button class='btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block' onclick='cordova.InAppBrowser.open(\""+link+"\", \"_system\", \"location=no\");'>Open System Browser</button>";
```

`link` is a variable that containes the URL, i.e. "http://www.google.com".
Thanks for reading.

that's what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add the plugin first and then use the **open()** method from **window** object and use the target as **_system**

```
window.open('http://www.google.com', '_system', 'location=no');
```

Comment: I alredy have added the plugin, I will try your suggestion.